# Display list of Favorited Posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial, favorites

Im made a User profile that displays a list of user created comments and posts but i also want to add a list of favorited posts .

currently i have  `<%= @user.favorites %>`

it only displays  `#<Favorite::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fad63371118>`

and a partial (views/favorites/_favorites.html.erb) of

```
<%= content_tag :div, class: 'media', id: "favorite-#{favorite.id}" do %>
<div class= "media">
 <div class= "media-body">
   <p> <%= favorite.post.body %></p>
 </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

it doesnt seem to be working as i planned it to .

Comment: add `.to_a`, convert association to array

Comment: @OlegSobchuk no need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

```
# note -, not =
<%- @user.favorites do |favorite| %>
  <%= render 'favorites/_favorites', favorite: favorite %>
<%- end%>
```

## UPD

According to [Leito](https://stackoverflow.com/users/637094/leito)'s comment, you could also do easier:

```
<%= render partial: @user.favorites %>
```

Comment: I think `<%= render partial: @user.favorites %>` should do the loop and look up the partial for you.